# Installing a C/C++ library with homebrew on M1 Macs

Tags: macos, homebrew, mac-mini, apple-silicon

In Linux, when a C/C++ library is installed through a package manager, the C/C++ compiler on the system is immediately able to find the installed library. I haven't used Intel Macs but this is definitely not the case in M1 Macs.

On M1 Macs, `homebrew` package manager installs software and libraries under `/opt` folder. It seems that `clang` that comes with XCode is not able to recognize this path so each time I compile my program against a particular library, I need to specify the library path using compiler's appropriate flag.

Is there a way to make `clang` compiler in M1 Macs recognize installed C/C++ library paths by default?

Comment: Re the C/C++ compiler on the system is immediately able to find the installed library. that is not strictly true. Nder Linux most libraries though  are hard coded to one place and the code using them has the same hard coding. In general all Unix has the same issues as you see in macos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add an environment variable as follows

```
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

to the file corresponding to the shell, like `~/.bash_profile` for bash.

Alternatively create CMake file with content like

```
link_directories("/opt/homebrew/lib")
include_directories("/opt/homebrew/include")
```

Or

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-L/opt/homebrew/lib " CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "-I/opt/homebrew/include " CACHE STRING "" FORCE )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I/opt/homebrew/include " CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

and create projects like `cmake -C ../link_dir.cmake -B ../build -S .`

Comment: @nmd_07 Also try `export CPATH=opt/homebrew/include`

Comment: @nohillside well, for `/opt/homebrew/include` that worked. I am not sure about `LDFLAGS` though.

Comment: So `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` seem to be the wrong variables. Tryp `CPATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` instead.